# Export article as PDF

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have noticed, that in Joomla 1.5 there was a PDF icon that could be shown next to the print end email icons  above the articles, but in Joomla 3.x it is not there any more.

I have been searching for an extension for this but so far without success.

Can anyone give me some advice on this?

Comment: I suspect the PDF icon/link was removed for good reason. In many (most?) cases the PDF was an exact copy of the original Joomla article. Duplicate content is never good for SEO, but the problems caused by it can be minimized. Whatever solution you choose be mindful of the possible duplicate content issue you may be creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, I would recommend the Phoca PDF Content plugin: http://www.phoca.cz/phocapdf-plugins

You may want to customize the icon in your template if it has custom styles for the email and print so that it all matches.  If you run into that situation, post the URL to an article once you have Phoca installed as well as the name of the template.

Answer (score 4):

The PDF icon has been removed since Joomla 1.6.
As an alternative you can use a 3rd party extension, have a look [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/print-a-pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Creating PDF's from articles comes with many problems, getting them to look correct is hard just because the styling of it is very different then a normal article. Using print css can be a better solution and I am sure there are extensions for that sort of thing.

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=pint&q=print

This is just a suggestion though, from personal experience, below is how I added PDF views in Joomla Sites.

There is a way to "re add" the pdf views from a programming perspective.

[http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_PDF_views](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_PDF_views)

This is for 2.5 however I have used it in up to 3.2 as well (not sure on 3.3).

It may be difficult to do but with an article override as well it is possible to re add the "pdf" button as well.

http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

This should allow you to add the extra button in all views you need. It does require some coding experience but the guides should help with that.